# Show and hide table column using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across this fiddle from a SO answer, that hides a table column once a button is clicked. What i want is the absolute opposite. I want it to be hidden by default, and then show and hide (toggle) when i click a button.

How can i achieve this?

Here's the fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDVS/407/)

HTML:

```
<table id="foo">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("foo").classList.toggle("hide2")'>Click me</button>
```

CSS:

```
#foo td {
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#foo.hide2 tr > *:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Do  the opposite man.. Hide the columns when you create it. On the click event show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `hide2` class initially to the element or execute the toggle statement once.

```css
#foo td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#foo.hide2 tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="foo" class="hide2">
  <!------------^^^^^^^^^^^-->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("foo").classList.toggle("hide2")'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! i was thinking it was something more complex, turns out adding the class solve it!

Comment: One question: if i want to show it when clicking a button, and then hide it again when clicking another button, how can i do it ?

Comment: @laker001 : use `...classList.add('hide2');` for hiding and  `...classList.remove('hide2');` for showing :)

Comment: @laker001 : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it with JQuery adding this line.

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnDVS/609/

And with CSS add it:

```
#foo td:nth-child(2) { display: none;}
```

And change it:

```
#foo.hide2 tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

To:

```
#foo.hide2 tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnDVS/610/